# Alternative constructor with inheritance (parent and 'grandparent')

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I am trying to make my alternative constructor for Foo3 work that is not supposed to need any inputs.

```
class Foo1:

    def __init__(self, x):
        """
        Constructor requires x
        """
        print("I am Foo1")

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls, some_list):
        """
        Alternative constructor
        """
        return cls(2)

class Foo2(Foo1):
    pass

class Foo3(Foo2):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Same constructor as Foo1 but x is always 5
        """
        super(Foo3, self).__init__(5)

    @classmethod
    def from_list(cls):
        """
        Alternative constructor
        Same as Foo1 from_list except some_list is always [1, 2, 3]
        """
        self = super(Foo2, Foo3).from_list(some_list=[1, 2, 3])
        return self

foo1_using_init = Foo1(2)
foo1_using_from_list = Foo1.from_list([5, 6, 7])

foo3_using_init = Foo3()
foo3_using_from_list = Foo3.from_list()  # broken
```

This is the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Usersp.py", line 37, in <module>
    foo3_using_from_list = Foo3.from_list()  # broken
  File "C:\Usersp.py", line 30, in from_list
    self = super(Foo2, Foo3).from_list(some_list=[1, 2, 3])
  File "C:\Userp.py", line 11, in from_list
    return cls(2)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Interesting, I see the problem now. How do I get around it though? @Matiiss

Answer (score 2):

When you use

```py
self = super().from_list(some_list=[1, 2, 3])
```

It ultimately ends up calling this

```py
return cls(2)
```

In that case it is the same as

```py
return Foo3(2)
```

But clearly the `__init__` method doesn't take any additional arguments so it will raise an error.

To fix this you can just use `*` to get all the arguments and then just ... ignore them:

```py
class Foo3(Foo2):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Same constructor as Foo1 but x is always 5
        """
        super().__init__(5)
```

Comment: Is using the *args method considered pythonic? It looks less readable but if it is a convention I will still use it.

Comment: Why does `self = super(Foo2, Foo3).from_list(some_list=[1, 2, 3])` not use the `__init__` from `Foo3`. Why does it call the `__init__` from `Foo1`

Comment: And can I make it use the `__init__` from Foo3 instead?

Comment: @Vader `*args` and `**kwargs` is usually how an arbitrary amount of arguments is handled. You can use other names too but usually they don't vary much from this, see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values) on this. The second question, `super().from_list(...)` doesn't on its own call any `__init__` methods, the function it calls, later calls `__init__` (`cls()`) by calling the passed class which in case if calling from `Foo3` is `Foo3`. So at the end it is calling `__init__` from `Foo3` which is why the arguments have to be handled